# Should the PHP community start using more descriptive Exceptions?

Tags: php, frameworks, exception

I work with Zend Framework a lot and I just took a peek at Kohana, and it strikes me as odd that this is a typical scenario in these frameworks:

```
throw Some_Components_Exception( 'invalid argument' );
```

Where I believe this wouldn't be much more useful:

```
throw Some_Components_InvalidArgumentException( 'whatever discription' );
```

Because it is easier to catch.

I suspect, but immediately admit it's prejudiced, that the former practice is common in the PHP community. Should we, the PHP community, start using these descriptive types of expections more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend using the Exception subtypes provided by SPL.  It allows calling code (either in a framework or in your app) to handle different types of exceptions differently.

A `DomainException` might indicate invalid user input, which you should report to the user and give them a chance to re-enter data.  A `BadMethodCallException` may indicate a flaw in your code, and you should log it and handle it a different way.

But these different exception scenarios have nothing to do with the class or component that threw the exception.  A `BadMethodCallException` should probably be handled similarly whether it happens in an MVC component or a DB access layer.

I was the project lead on the Zend Framework through its 1.0 release.  I wanted to reorganize the exception hierarchy, and I thought it was an arbitrary decision (prior to my joining the project) to use a single exception for every component.  It didn't make sense.

Unfortunately, rearchitecting the exceptions wasn't as important as getting the product to its 1.0 release milestone.  I had to follow the priority on schedule that Zend set for the project, and to do that, practically everything that wasn't strictly necessary to get to the feature-complete release had to be deferred.

Comment: Invalid user input shouldn't throw an exception since you can expect these.

Comment: @koen: but if you have a layered setup where validation takes place in a higher level and somehow invalid data slipped through to your domain model, it should IMO.